# How can I set up geo reads in an Azure Cosmos DB application

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-node-sdk

So it would seem that if I use a connection policy with preferred locations the read requests will use the locations in order specified in that preference...regardless of the geographic location of the request.   If I do not use the preferred location property, then the reads all come from the write location.  How do I set up to application to do reads using the closest geographic data center to the request?

Comment: Do you have geographically distributed instances of your application that is communicating with Cosmos? If so, how are you currently distributing traffic between them, something like Azure Traffic Manager?

Comment: No I am not.  I just have one application deployed to one region.  Do I need to deploy a version of the app to each region?  And if so, what is the best way to do so knowing I need to have a different preferred location list for each region?

Comment: If you only have your application in one region then all requests (from Cosmos perspective) are coming from the same region anyways. Regardless of where in the world the client request came from it would be routed to whatever region your app is in and then all the way back to the client...